# Saddle point of the Lagrangian

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider a standard constrained optimisation problem with an equality constraint.

Maximize $f(x,y)$   s.t.       $g(x,y)=c$.

We construct the Lagrangian to solve this problem.

$\mathcal{L}(x,y)=f(x,y)-\lambda(g(x,y)-c)$

The first order conditions give us the stationary point of the Lagrangian.

$\mathcal{L}_x=0$

$\mathcal{L}_y=0$

$g(x,y)=c$

Say the vector $(x*,y*,\lambda*)$ solves this set of equations. Is this point a saddle point of the Lagrangian?

Further, does $(x*,y*,\lambda*)$ maximize $\mathcal{L}(x,y)$ as well?

Comment: If the functional is stricly concave, the stationary point cannot be a saddle point: you can grasp some intuition of it thinking about concave function of real variables

Comment: Then how do we establish that the function is maximixed?

Comment: A function is not maximized on a saddle point

Comment: intuitively, a saddle point is when the function is max in along one variable and min along the other variable (just like the saddle on the horseback)

Comment: @farruhota I understand what is a saddle point. What I am trying to ask is about the relation (if any exists) between the optimum of the constrained problem and the stationary point of the Lagrangian we construct to solve the said problem. Is the optimum of the constrained problem also the maximum of the Lagrangian?

Comment: optimum is max or min, while stationary point is max, min or saddle point. So, if the stationary point is a saddle point, it is not optimum.